# Laravel 5.5: Paginator styles disappear

Tags: php, laravel

i took a screenshot from my paginator.. it looks weird

[image: Screenshot1]

I did this on my controller:

```
$customers = Customer::paginate(3);
```

and just this on my view (out of table tags):

```
{{ $customers->render() }}
```

Same on page 1,2

What's wrong?

Comment: Could be a CSS issue. Have you looked at the output HTML source?

Comment: I did it and there is no problems with that, already fixed adding this:  {{ $customers->links('pagination::bootstrap-4') }} why laravel 5.5 makes it so difficult? i miss 5.3 =/

Comment: If you have already fixed the problem, you should add it as an answer and accept it, not in a comment. An answer will make it clear the question has been resolved already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fixed adding this: {{ $customers->links('pagination::bootstrap-4') }} why laravel 5.5 makes it so difficult? i miss 5.3 =/

Comment: I assume the vast majority of projects using bootstrap are still on version 3 and having default pagination set to bootstrap 4 would be a bigger pain for updating projects, than it is for new projects to add `'pagination::bootstrap-4'`. Might be more difficult for you, but easier for most.

Comment: Yeah but that is it so difficult to change a lot of views that contains only {{ $customers->links() }} without that line, it would be so easy configuring bootstrap versions in just one file.. thanks for that -1

Comment: Paginator has a property called `defaultView`. You can always set it through 4th parameter of the constructor method - `$options`, if you prefer that way. As for the -1, that wasn't me, but with comments like that you're bound to get some dislikes. There, a +1 from me, since it's still a correct answer at the end of the day (provided whoever sees this know you're using bootstrap 4).

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
{{$customer->links()}}
```

i think that paginator default laravel.

Comment: add some description to your answer

Comment: oh oke bro. i give some desc.